# Find and list every element's id value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all the found elements within a `<div>`, but by default it stops when it found the first occurrence, but I want it to list every found element's `id` value.

So this doesn't work:

```
listy = $("DIV").find("SPAN").attr("id");
```

I've been experimenting with `.get` and `.map`, but I think they're not what I want..

Comment: Most javascript-jQuery developers use lowercase letters for tag names, so `div` instead of `DIV` and `span` instead of `SPAN` believe it or not using `DIV SPAN` is like shouting...

Comment: @gdoron +1 I'd rather say: *"it's like swearing"* :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
listy = $("div").find("span").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Without `find` is even **better**:

```
listy = $("div span").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S6GL4/)

If you want only `<span>` with `id` attribute defined, change the selector to:

```
$(div span[id]).map(...)
```

---

If you want all the `id`s as a string:

```
listy = $("div span").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get().join('');
```

The parameter of `join` is the delimiter, e.g. `.join('-')` or `.join(',')` or without: `.join('')`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way?

```
var ids = [];

$("div span").each(function() {
  if (this.id) {
    ids.push(this.id);
  }
});
```

attr() method will always return first elements attribute only.

Comment: +1, but I'll be happy if you can change `DIV` and `SPAN` to lower case, it bothers my eyes... :)

Comment: thx! changed ;) i just copied that piece of code directly from question :)

Comment: and removing the `find` will make the code easier to read and faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
var listy = '';

$("div span").each(function(){  
  listy += this.id ;  
});
```

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ewuwar/edit#javascript,html,live)

---

Or like:

```
var listy = [];                           // create array

$("div span[id]").each(function(){        // span with ID data
  listy.push( this.id );                  // push ID names into array
});

// Now use listy.join(); to see the list
// you can also do: listy+''  to transform it into string.
```

[jsBIn demo 2](http://jsbin.com/ewuwar/2/edit)

Comment: If you want it in a string format, what do you think about this: `$("div span").map(function(){  
  return this.id;  
}).get().join('');` ?

Comment: Thanks, Nice one bro! I like `+=` :)

Comment: @gdoron Thanks bro! Congrats for the bronze... or it's a silver again? ;)

Comment: bronze... silver is 25, gold is 100.

Comment: [Now I got the enlightened badge.](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=601179) `:)` SILVER! Tell 88 of your friends to upvote it, and I have a shiny gold badge. `:)`

Comment: @gdoron Wow. I like this badge! +1 from me ;)